# Opening another android browser from chrome (android) via href

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, flash, android-intent, intentfilter

I have a website which needs to play flash, unfortunately, android chrome does not support playing flash. As a solution to this, I need to open the URL to another browser which is dolphin browser that has a built in flash player. The question now is how am i going the launch the dolphin browser and pass the url? I have tried using [Android Intents](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents) but still no luck. I also have this line of code:

```
<a href="intent://my_url_to_open#Intent;scheme=http;package=mobi.mgeek.TunnyBrowser;action:ACTION_VIEW;category=android.intent.category.BROWSABLE;end"
```

What am I missing? Or did I make it the wrong way?

Comment: Pleas note that Android has also a per app setting to handle URLs, maybe take a look at that. And why should you change the browser and not just already start with that one that supports Flash?

Comment: @chade_ The web app is mainly built to run in chrome so some styles and features will not work the same as in it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
String url = "http://www.example.com";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```

Note that, when you will fire up this intent, there should be an option to chose browsers. If you already set a default browser, then you have to remove that default browser.